# How to get name in spacebar {{ <some name> }} in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I want to get the property name of spacebar Ex.

```
<template name="example">
  {{#with object}}
    {{level1.level2}}  
    {{permission.post.create}}  
    {{permission.post.read}}
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

After I click on it I want to get the name of property

```
Template.example.events({
    "click <selector>" : function(event,template){

        //Question how to get name "level1.level2" ,"permission.post.create" ,"permission.post.read"
        var name1 = ??? // I want name1 = "level1.level2" (string not it value)     

        //After I get the property name I can use it in MongoDB query like this
        var key = {}
        key[name1] = "newvalue" // now I got { 'level1.level2' : 'newvalue'}
        Model.update({_id : "abc"}, key)  

    }
})
```

It very useful when you have to update deep nested document Ex.. table of permission list with checkbox

Comment: Your event handler and your template share the same [context](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/) so a `console.log(this)` in the handler should tell you want you need to know. It should be just `this.object.level1.level2` etc. In meteor you shouldn't need to add `data-` attributes to your templates (as in the answers below) *unless* they a required by a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

what about to add `data-` properties to the html elements, and then when you receive the event, you can do something like var -id = $(event.target).attr("data-id"); I didnt understand completely your question neither have access to you data structure but assuming that you want to get an information from the object that you render in a html element. My suggestion its the follow:

```
<template name="mytemplate">
   <a href="" data-id="{{object.level2}}" data-name="{{object.name}}">{{ object.name }}</a>
</template>

Template.<name>.events({
    "click <selector>" : function(event,template){
        //Question how to get name "level1.level2" ,"permission.post.create" ,"permission.post.read"

          var name1 = $(event.target).attr("data-name");    
          //do whatever with you variable 

    }
})
```

Sorry if this its not what are you looking.

Answer (score 0):

**ncubica** your answer was close that what I want.

I use

```
<template name="mytemplate">
  <a href="" data-name="level1.level2">{{level1.level2}}</a>
</template>
```

Then I can use it like this

```
"click .toggle-checked" : function(event,template){
    var pName = $(event.target).attr("data-name")
    var updateAttr ={}
    updateAttr[pName] = "theNewValue"
    Collection.update({_id : this._id},{ $set : updateAttr})
}
```

Thank you for your hint.